# Selecting one of many services as the service to use

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

**Scenario:**

- I'm using the dependency-injection component as a stand-alone component. No bundles/symfony-framework and stuff.
- I have a set of services all being responsible for similar things, e.g. for writing data to the hard disk by different ways (e.g. by ftp, direct file operations, storing into a db, ...)
- Each of these services requires different configuration (e.g. sql credentials, ftp credentials, ...)
- I want to define one of these services as the "general service to use" for other services to have a dependency on.
- Which service to use is configured by a parameter

**Example:**

Given these simplified parameter and service definitions:

```
<parameter key="file.adapterType">direct</parameter>
<service id="file.db" />
<service id="file.ftp" />
<service id="file.direct" />
```

I'd like to define an alias to the service I actually want to use

```
<service id="file.adapter" alias="file.%file.adapterType%"/>
```

for other services simply relying on this service:

```
<service id="photos">
    <argument type="service" id="file.adapter" />
</service>
```

**What I have tried so far:**

- Defining an alias with an parameter in it's alias-id. However the parameter within the alias-id does not get resolved.
- Defining the id directly within the argument-tag - again the parameter is not resolved her:

  ```
  <service id="photo">
      <argument type="service" id="file.%file.adapterType%" />
  </service>
  ```
- Creating a factory. The get-method receives the parameter and the di-container and returns the corresponding service:

  ```
  public function get(ContainerInterface $container, $parameter) 
  {
      return $container->get('file.' . $parameter);
  }
  ```

  However the container does not register itself as a service. Registering it beforehand does not take affect when loading the configuration from a file (resulting in an error message "service 'container' not found"):

  ```
  $container->set("container", $container);
  $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/services'));
  $loader->load('fileadapter.xml'); // << gives error
  $container->get("container"); // << working
  ```

**Other alternatives?**

I can't set the alias after loading the configuration file as there are services within the file that have a dependency on the alias.

Anyone got other ideas on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I believe you were on the right track with the third bullet point in the "What I've tried so far" section, except that the service container does register itself as a service, but it's called `service_container`, not `container`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you can move `file.*` services to a file and the services that uses `file.adapter` to another file and create the `file.adapter` alias while create the alias in-between loading the files. For example

```
$loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/services'));
$loader->load('fileadapter.xml'); 

$defaultAdapterId = "file." . $container->getParameter('file.adapterType');
if($container->hasDefinition($defaultAdapterId)) {
    $container->setAlias('file.adapter', $defaultAdapterId);
}

$loader->load('other_services.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

now (since version 2.7 actually), you can use symfony expression language to the same thing using configuration only

look at here http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html